# Troubleshooting a half-dead circuit in my home

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

tl;dr - a circuit with 7 outlets on it only has one working. I've replaced the breaker, every outlet, every light switch, and visually inspected every wire, but can't figure out how to fix it.

---

I've been trying to fix a half-dead circuit in my home for the last several weeks. My house painters plugged their sanders into an external outlet and tripped a breaker, and ever since then 6 outlets and 3 ceiling lights have been without power. Oddly, the circuit has 7 outlets on it, the outlet that I assume is the first on the circuit is still functioning correctly (hence my calling it a "half-dead" circuit). The second outlet on the circuit registers power on a voltage checker, but when I plug a circuit tester into the outlet it shows that it's dead (the internet tells me that's a sign of an open neutral somewhere in the circuit).

Everything I've read online has told me to check every connection on the circuit. I started with replacing the breaker, since then I've replaced every outlet, every wingnut, every light switch. I've visually inspected every wire I have access to (i.e. I haven't started knocking holes in my drywall), and I see no signs of overheating. Unfortunately, none of this has helped. I had an electrician come out and he said it seemed like a GFCI had tripped somewhere in the circuit, because he was able to detect his circuit tracer but neither of us were able to find it.

Given all the stuff I've tried above, I've run out of ideas, so any suggestions would be immensely helpful.

Thanks,

-Nick

Comment: Are the outlets connected by the screws or the push ins?  Replace all push ins to the screws.  If no push ins, then you probably have a broken wire in the wall/s between the outlets(and maybe fried mouse).  A multimeter should give readings of 120v hot to neutral and hot to ground, and 0v between neutral and ground.  Different readings is a problem.  Was the breaker correct for your panel? They are not mix and match type.

Comment: @crip659 thanks for the input. The original outlets were backstab/push-in type, I saw someone else suggest to redo them with screws and hooks, so I did that as I was replacing all of the outlets. The breaker is the same type exactly, I brought the old one with me to Home Depot to verify. I'll see if I can find my multimeter to check your suggestion, thank you!

Comment: The multimeter will probably only limit the section of wire/cable that needs extra checking.  Outlet one  reads correct but outlet two does not, then that section in the wall/floor/ceiling is probably the problem section, if you have replaced the outlets and used the screws/connections correctly.  Testing is usually much cheaper than replacing good devices.  Beside the push in connections, most simple(outlets/light fixtures) electrical devices do not break down/wear out in most cases.

Comment: With a volt meter and a long extension cord you can test every outlet in question. Plug in the extension cord to a known-good outlet and carry its end to a non-working outlet. Use the volt meter to measure between cord neutral and outlet hot; cord hot and outlet neutral; cord ground and outlet hot; cord ground and outlet neutral. The results will help reveal which of the conductors are interrupted.

Comment: @crip659 Since the old outlets were backstab ones, they are almost certainly poor quality and replacing them almost certainly justified even if they were "working". Hopefully OP used "spec grade" or better new replacements.

Comment: You had one working outlet. So, obviously, replacing the breaker was pointless, because without a working breaker, you would have zero working outlets. There's either a broken wire or a *hidden/lost/you don't know where it is, anyway* GFCI between the working outlet and the other things that don't work.  (or between the breaker and the other things that don't work, if they are not fed from the working outlet.)